# How to import Excel column with $ and % into SQL DB using SSIS package creation

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm developing SSIS package using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

```
Datasource - Excelfile

Destination - SQL DB
```

In my excel file following values present.

[image]

I need to insert this same values to DB table. but in DB "%" not present. same $ symbol also not inserted into DB

Please guide how to insert excel sheet values with % and $ symbol in to DB table.

MY SSIS package Dataflow as below

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the $ or % stored in the db. Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Plus the value you are seeing in the Excel might be due to formating and not the actual value in the cell. As commented by jChao you would be better off storing the value in the db alone and applying $ or % in your presentation layer.

Comment: After the data is inserted into your DB. Does 99% show as .99?

Comment: @JChao If i insert 99% it's show as 0.9899999999999999 in DB

Comment: Make sure the cells in excel are formatted as text.

Comment: @JChao It's needed to inert % and $ with value. If there is any way Present.

Comment: @JChao If i formatted as text A1 cell then i enter 99% its store in DB as 99% . But If i copy value for B1 cell 95% to A1 it again change to 99 . Text format automatically convert to percentage format.

Comment: Format all the cells to text. At least it sounds like we've figured out the issue which ended up being the way excel is formatting the cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Excel usually stores numeric values unadorned.** The settings for how to format number values (like whether to use $ or %, whether to round and whether to add commas) are stored separately. As @TMNT2014 and @JChao indicate in the comments, likely what's going on is that SSIS is reading the raw numeric values out of the spreadsheet. You're not getting $ or % because those symbols technically aren't a part of the cells' values the way Excel sees things.

Regardless of how Excel sees things, you want $ and % displayed with the numbers your SSIS package is importing. Several ways of achieving this come to mind:

- **Import and store the raw numeric values in your database. Apply formatting (like $ and %) when/after your fetch data out of the database.** This is the generally preferred method for dealing with this situation.

  One of several advantages with this approach is that the database server will properly sort the values. Compare the difference between how 1, 2, 19 and 100 are sorted when stored as numbers vs. when stored as dollar sign-prefixed strings:

  ```
  Numeric Values  String Values
  ==============  =============
  1               $1
  2               $100
  19              $19
  100             $2
  ```

  However, it sounds like this option won't work in your situation.
- If you need users to be able to retrieve values with $ or % included directly from the database:

  - You could **store data as described under option #1 and then create a view which applies the desired formatting** (adds the %, rounds the number to two digits, etc.). This approach might give you the best of both worlds: ease of importing from the spreadsheet/storing numbers using numeric db datatypes along with allowing your users to fetch properly formatted values out the database without extra work being involved.
  - You could **import data as you are currently then use SSIS's Derived Column transform to format the data** (add $/%, round, etc.).
- If the data needs to be stored exactly the way it is displayed in Excel, you could **change how the spreadsheets are created.** Try setting the relevant cells' formatting to `Text` before entering data into the cell. As the legend for text formatting says "Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell. The cell is displayed exactly as entered." Not only are text cells displayed as entered, they are stored as entered. When you import from a text cell, you get exactly what the user entered.
- If the data needs to be stored exactly as entered and changing how spreadsheets are created isn't an option, you might be able to **use a Script Component to copy the as-displayed values** from the source spreadsheet into a temporary spreadsheet via which you then would import. This could be coded in VB or C# using one of the Microsoft Office APIs.

Comment: Your detailed Explanation help full for me. i check with your solution and tell you what happen.